# Enable and disable a broadcast in kotlin

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, kotlin

I wrote this code to enable and disable a broadcast:

```
        val broadcastState = when(state){
        true -> {PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED}
        false -> {PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED}
    }

    val component:ComponentName=ComponentName(this,DateChangeReceiver::class)
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(component,
            broadcastState,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
```

But Android Studio gave some error till I changed `component` to this:

```
val component:ComponentName=ComponentName(this,DateChangeReceiver::class.java)
```

Based on [this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getclass) it should be used to  retrieve the Java class of an object, but all my classes are in kotlin. So I'm wondering if I'm doing it right.

Comment: i want to do the same thing but i don't know where to deplare the component, where do you put this code ?

Answer (score 1):

It's giving you error because the [ComponentName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html) class expects a context and a Java class. Since your class was written in Kotlin, you should get the class by doing as you said:

`DateChangeReceiver::class.java`

or

`DateChangeReceiver::javaClass`

If the ComponentName expected a Kotlin class, there would be no problem by doing it without the `.java`

You'll face this using some Java libraries.

Also check [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html) about reflection in Kotlin. As stated there:

> Note that a Kotlin class reference is not the same as a Java class reference. To obtain a Java class reference, use the .java property on a KClass instance.

Comment: when I use it without .java or ::class.java, I get an error which says I should use a `class` or `String!` as the second parameter

Comment: Yes, because it has more than one public constructor. One of them takes the context as first parameter and .class as the second and the other takes the context as first and a String representing the class name as stated on the first link